# Buck converter design (311V to 3.3V)

Tags: power-supply, power, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics

I'm trying to make a buck converter which produces an output voltage of 3.3V with a load of around 1 amps when the input is around 220v AC.
This basically means converting from 311v DC to 3.3v DC.
I'm basing my circuit on

[image]

What I wanted to ask, is such a circuit feasible? Practically not theoretically. It seems quite simple.
I calculated the inductance at around 26uH, and capacitance to be a minimum of around 50uf, However I'm using 100uF on both the input and output capacitors..
I have a duty cycle of around 1% since the output voltage is tiny in comparison to the input.

Comment: For safety purposes, you would want some kind of isolation from mains voltage.

Comment: take care of the switching frequency, if you take the Fsw to high the 1% duty becomes very short. And as a result, the turn-on and turn-off time of the FET can become a problem.

Comment: What’s your output current and max allowable voltage ripple on the output and max current ripple on your output cap?

Comment: That is a very simple circuit used to describe the basics of how a buck converter works, it is not a practical circuit that will work reliably, efficiently and safely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What I wanted to ask, is such a circuit feasible? Practically not theoretically.

I'll go with a "no". The time you'll spend in such an open-loop configuration to actually make things stabilize at the voltage you want will be quite substantial, and the slightest change in temperature will change how the transistor works, so: don't try this. Also, you'll need a >> 300V breakdown bijunction transistor, and that's going to be unnecessarily expensive, and probably waste a lot of power, thus will be very rapidly changing in characteristics due to heating up, thus making everything worse.

Also: at 1% duty cycle it is very hard to maintain stability of anything.

> It seems quite simple.

That's because it's a very textbook example, seemingly taken out of context. No one in their right mind would recommend building something like this!

> I calculated the inductance at around 26uH, and capacitance to be a minimum of around 50uf, However I'm using 100uF on both the input and output capacitors.. I have a duty cycle of around 1% since the output voltage is tiny in comparison to the input.

Exactly, and because this circuit was meant to *illustrate the principle*, not *to work at edge conditions*, it will work miserably, if at all.

Don't do that: copy circuits from random websites which try to teach you *basics*. If you want a power supply, there's ICs for that, which take all the burden of actually building something that works from your shoulder: In practice, a switch-mode converter would *measure* its output, and adjust its duty cycle automatically to achieve the desired output. That's much cleverer than just calculating things and hoping for the best in terms of component tolerances and parasitic effects (which will absolutely ruin your day here).

---

regarding how to build that:

Actually, I'd recommend not building something like this yourself. 300V can and will kill you and the ones you love. Considering a minimum textbook example might be a sign of "needs a bit of experience" before you want to build things that will potentially electrocute you.

However, if you insist: You'll need something with galvanic isolation between the primary and secondary side here to even fulfill the most basic safety requirements (i.e. to satisfy your will to live).

That means you want a flyback transformer bases switch-mode power supply, where you probably have a switch which switches the primary side of a transformer on and off – on the secondary side, you'd have the voltage and/or current sensing, and you'd have some way to transport the signal "voltage high enough" to the switch controller on the primary side.

The fact that your transformer can have any winding ratio (not just 1:1) means that you don't have to operate at a 1% duty cycle – which would be very good, because such marginal duty cycles make it very hard to regulate stably.

You'll probably have to wind that transformer yourself, or order it special-made. Maybe you can buy one that fits your needs.

Such switch controllers can be bought relatively cheaply, and they're not totally out of this world in terms of complexity of what they do internally, but you'll need quite a firm grasp on electronics and control theory to fully appreciate what happens. However, you don't need to understand them fully – they come with good application notes explaining how to build such a step down converter.

Look at *ON Semi*'s website. They have a lot of such "off-line controllers"; things like the FSCQ1265RT integrate the switching transistor (which is a MOSFET at these voltages), and you'll "only" have to calculate the values for the rest of the components. For many of these, evaluation boards with online schematics are available. Again, it's not overly complicated, but it's not a good beginner project, because you can kill yourself, and because shorted out things connected to your 300V power source probably go "poof".

Comment: +1 in total agreement - the op needs to use a flyback design and not buck.

Comment: "Load of 1 amps" - it's right there in the first sentence.

Comment: @Arsenal now I feel rightfully stupid!

Comment: @MarcusMüller well it's not gonna change much of your answer - basically the circuit + question combination speaks for little experience.

Comment: @Arsenal true, changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you for the straightforward answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So it's not possible even with a load of 1A?
actually I did some research regarding the matter and according to the datasheet, the Transistor should be able to handle the switching frequency. However, as you said a duty cycle of 1% does seem sort of unreliable.
Thing is I didn't want to use a transformer because I heard that they take a lot of space usually and this project requires a somewhat small circuit. 
How much do you think I should step it down by the transformer, before I can bring it down to 3.3V by DC-DC... everybody is recommending flyback... I'll check it out as well

Comment: I think my answer was pretty clear on that. No, this circuit **will not work**, **has a high chance of killing you** and is **not what you need**.  (I feel very stupid for having to repeat that.)

Comment: and: you don't use a transformer to step down first, the transformer is *switched* and is the central part of the voltage converter. You **really** need to read up on flyback converters!

Comment: @MarcusMüller are there perhaps any other transformerless methods, which would be more reliable than this one? I'm doing this as part of an internship task, and my supervisor wants to avoid using a transformer... For size, costs..etc
Thank you

Comment: Aaaaaaargh. I gave you a clear answer.

Comment: RESEARCH FLY BACK. really not that hard.

Comment: Your flyback transformer is *smaller* than what you'd need as a Buck converter. Stop trying to avoid a transformer. It'll ducking save a life.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you bro, I actually did before I even checked buck converters... But when I suggested it to my supervisor he was like that transformer will need too many turns... and is how I ended up here haha.
Thank you for the help, I'll talk to my supervisor

Comment: I feel really stupid for even discussing this: when dealing with 300 V, you need isolation. You need an isolating down converter.

Comment: God. This is so stupid. You're not even reading what I write. You don't use a transformer to directly convert ac to a lower voltage ac. The flyback transformer is the inductor in your step-down converter of flyback type. As I have been saying multiple times now, you'll need one.

Comment: And please don't "bro" me.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for clarifying the misconception, do you mind if I message you on chat if I face a problem with the flyback?

Comment: please don't. Ask a new question explaining exactly what you've researched or done, and precisely state what you need help with :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller alrighty sure thing, thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons to **not implement** your circuit without transformer:

- It has no isolation between input and output - it's dangerous for most use cases.
- Switching transistor needs to have both high voltage and high current capabilities.
- If switching transistor breaks, all 300 V will be applied to the load and will burn it.

Transformer (flyback topology) solves all that problems, and I suggest to use it.

Also, making AC/DC coverters is not right starting point without enough knowledge and experience. It's complex and literally dangerous. May be, it's better to start with low voltage converter circuits (less than 30 V).